# OpenLayers Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo does not send request to geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I'm refactoring the code used to getfeatureinfo from geoserver running on port 8080 at http://www.edpp.cz/zul_mapa-povodnoveho-planu-mesta/. The old version uses OpenLayers.loadURL and successfully requests the response from the server. The code is like:

```
map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {            
        var params = {
                REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
                EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
                SERVICE: "WMS",
                VERSION: "1.1.1",
                X: e.xy.x,
                Y: e.xy.y,
                INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
                QUERY_LAYERS: layers_on,
                FEATURE_COUNT: 1,
                Layers: layers_on,
                Styles: '',
                WIDTH: map.size.w,
                HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                format: format,
                srs: map.layers[0].params.SRS};

            if(offline)
                OpenLayers.loadURL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", params, this, setHTML, setHTML);
            else
                OpenLayers.loadURL("http://www.edpp.cz/mapinfo/geoserver/wms", params, this, setHTML, setHTML);

        OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
    });
```

With the new code I try something like this:

```
popup = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: offline ? 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms' : 'http://www.edpp.cz/mapinfo/geoserver/wms',
            layers: unbaseLayers,
            layerUrls: offline ? ['http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms'] : ['http://www.edpp.cz/mapinfo/geoserver/wms'],
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            queryVisible: true,
            maxFeatures: 1,
            eventListeners: {
                getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                    if (console) {
                        console.log(event);
                    }
                    if (event.text.length > 1088) { // nezobrazí prázdné bubliny
                        map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                            "popup", 
                            map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                            null,
                            event.text,
                            null,
                            true
                        ));
                    }
                },
                nogetfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                    if (console) {
                        console.log(event);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

If I look into Firebug network log, I see that the clicking the map doesn't send any request to the geoserver (it runs fine on localhost though). Is this just a proxy related problem? I've already read about need to set up a proxy when running geoserver on the different port than a website. But it's really puzzling me there is no request being sent. Might it be a typo? I can't see any.

What if I am not able to set up a proxy, do I have any other option?

PS: All I get as a result is object of nogetfeatureinfo type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the cross-domain request.
The problem is not related on which port Geoserver is listening, the problem is that you can't do an AJAX request (getFeatureInfo in your case) on different domains.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy